# wpf thread error

Tags: wpf, multithreading

i have Observable collection object bounded to a treeView:

```
MainTreeView.ItemsSource = ((App)Application.Current).TucOC;
```

the problem is that when i'm updating the ((App)Application.Current).TucOC this way:

```
_tucActivity.Add(new TucActivity(TucActivityEnum.Approve, null));
```

i get the following error:
This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate wpf objects only from UI thread. The error you get states you did it from a different thread.
Simply get the Dispatcher from Application.Current, and call

```
_tucActivity.Add(new TucActivity(TucActivityEnum.Approve, null));
```

from it

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Normal, () => _tucActivity.Add(new TucActivity(TucActivityEnum.Approve, null)));
```

Comment: doing so shows the following error message:

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: This syntax isn't entirely legal (priority comes 2nd) but the idea is sound.

Comment: a little fix:
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>  _tucActivity.Add(new TucActivity(TucActivityEnum.Approve, null))));

now it works